# Does anyone know how to SQL this query in Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a first database in the following format:

```
transaction_time  id
2009-12-12 12:12  12345
2009-12-12 12:13  12346
...               ...
```

The second database is in the following format:

```
id                name
12345             abc
12346             bcd
...               ...
```

I would like to write a query in Standard SQL for Google Big Query to count all occurrences of the same id on the same date and then return the name for the occurence (as in an Excel `VLOOKUP`).

I think it would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  DATETIME "2008-12-25 15:30:00" as original,
  DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME "2008-12-25 15:30:00", DAY) as truncated

select t2.name, t1.id
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.request_time
```

Can anybody confirm? Or is there a `GROUP BY` function in Standard SQL for Big Query? I couldn't seem to find one!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select date(t1.request_time) as dte, count(*)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.request_time
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Of course Standard SQL supports `GROUP BY` -- it is a very functional database from a querying perspective.

Or this?

```
select t2.name, count(*)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.request_time
where date(t1.request_date) = date('2008-12-25')
group by t2.name;
```